# How to broadcast a custom Linux signal from a kernel module to all running processes

Tags: c, linux-kernel

I have written a kernel module that supplies some information about a hardware interrupt to user-space. Currently, the user-space application uses IOCTL to send its PID `x` to the kernel module. The kernel module then uses this PID to find the task and send the signal:

```
#define CUSTOM_SIGNAL 44
struct siginfo info;
memset(&info, 0, sizeof(struct siginfo));
info.si_signo = CUSTOM_SIGNAL;
info.si_code = SI_QUEUE;
info.si_int = 0;
struct task_struct *t = pid_task(find_pid_ns(x, &init_pid_ns), PIDTYPE_PID);
send_sig_info(CUSTOM_SIGNAL, &info, t);
```

This works really well. However, I find it rather tricky to maintain a dynamic list of PID receivers for a single signal. For this reason I would like to broadcast the signal be default to all running processes (so they need not register to be notified -- it just happens).

One example I can think of that mimics this behaviour is the system shutdown signal. Is it possible to simply broadcast my CUSTOM_SIGNAL, or do I need to iterate over all PIDs, sending one-by-one as above. Or is there a special task representing broadcast?

Comment: Oof, I really wouldn't advise this. Some process not under your control may have decided to use 44 as a userspace-raised signal for some other purpose.

Comment: I agree with @Sneftel -- it's unusual and kind of ugly to broadcast a signal like this (I don't think the system shutdown signal really works this way BTW). Anyway, why not simply have interested processes create a separate thread that blocks in an ioctl (or even a read) until a hardware interrupt occurs? No reason to use a signal at all, simply return the fact of an interrupt by unblocking the ioctl/read. This maintains a clean association between process and driver. (And you could always have this thread send a signal to its own PID if you need it that way.)

Comment: This sounds horrible.  If the default disposition for the signal is not SIG_IGN, so the signal is never delivered to a process unless it requests it, there will be major problems.  I don't recommend trying to suggest this to the Linux Kernel Mailing List; I'd be tolerably certain it would be shot down in flames, or laughed out of court, in a very short time.  It simply isn't the way things are done.

Comment: Thank you to everybody for pointing out that the direction I have taken is incorrect. I have decided to drop the use of signals entirely and use a threaded poll of the ioctl, as advised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is downright incorrect.

> I have written a kernel module that supplies some information about a
>   hardware interrupt to user-space. Currently, the user-space
>   application uses IOCTL to send its PID x to the kernel module. The
>   kernel module then uses this PID to find the task and send the signal

First off, you have access to calling thread task structure by the means of **current**. Obtaining a PID like this and then finding it makes no sense whatsoever.

Also your code sample suggests you don't lock RCU, which is a bug you would learn about if you had debug enabled.

> This works really well. However, I find it rather tricky to maintain a
>   dynamic list of PID receivers for a single signal. For this reason I
>   would like to broadcast the signal be default to all running processes
>   (so they need not register to be notified -- it just happens).

This is similarly wrong on its principle. You will cause spurious wake ups and that has potential for a lot of weird-ass fun (not everything is as 'atomic' as people think).

Instead create a device driver to which a file descriptor can be obtained. Interested threads will **poll** the descriptor and that's how they will learn about the event.

Comment: First kernel module that I've written, so I'm likely to make a few mistakes. Thankfully, I haven't tried to push anything upstream :) I appreciate you helping with my learning curve.