# Linux kernel module send signal to process on hardware interrupt

Tags: python, c, linux-kernel, interrupt, kernel-module

I am working with *BeagleBone* Black which has *gpio* pins configurable via kernel module. In educational purposes I am developing a module able to  attach an interrupt on *gpio* state change.

My idea was that I have an interface in Python which sends *pid* to device(kernel module) and thus waiting for the signal on hardware interrupt from kernel space to perform a certain action(method).

So the logic goes as follows:

- Python process sets a handler function callable on signal *SIGIO*
- Python process sends his *pid* and *gpio* pin id to kernel module
- Kernel module receives a *pid* and *gpio id* from python process; registering gpio pin to specific *irq* number in IVT table(accomplishing this with simple kernel function) and registering a kernel handler function for this *irq* number
- On hardware interrupt(*gpio* state has changed) the kernel handler function is invoked and the (python) task is found via *pid* associated to *irq* number and signal is sent as *SIGIO* to Python process
- Python process receives this signal and the python handler function is invoked

This works quite well, but I run to a problem, what if Python process has several handlers for different gpio pins. Than all handler functions are invoked, which is a bad behavior. I searched online and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30110809/how-to-broadcast-a-custom-linux-signal-from-a-kernel-module-to-all-running-proce) question where the guy is advised strongly not to do this kind of kernel-user space communication and to use *polling* as a way to learn about the event happened.

As the alternative I am supposed to *poll* from python process on specific *gpio* pin. The question is, isn't the interrupt technique better? I mean this is just a common logic, the python process isn't waiting(busy) for gpio state to change, when hardware interrupt is invoked he is than and only than informed about the event and thus only than uses cpu time.

I probably don't understand what is going on under the hood, and that's why not seeing the *polling* technique as the way to do it.

I am also backed up with some working code, so if it needs some clarification I can show it.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Doesn't GPIO natively support poll? (see doc on [value](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/gpio/sysfs.txt))

Comment: @myaut: Yes, it does, if the pin supports interrupts, and `edge` is set to rising, falling, or both.

Comment: @Steven: No, the interrupt technique is not better, because `poll()` is *not* a busy wait. Think of `poll()`, `epoll()` and `select()` (and perhaps `sigwait()`, `sigwaitinfo()`, and `pause()` as well) as slightly different ways the thread can tell the kernel that *"Here's the list of stuff I'm interested in. Wake me when / return to me when / I shall sleep until there is something that interests me."*

Comment: @NominalAnimal Thanks for the tip. I wasn't aware that `poll()` is not a busy wait. I am writing a driver in educational purposes, so I guess I will implement the same thing.